# mysql join 2 columns to order by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, concatenation

Having a real struggle with something. I have a list of fixtures that have the following:

> hometeam, awayteam, date, time, season, competition.

I want to be able to join/group hometeam and awayteam so I can then group my results by this. So basically I would only get one fixture per team. I obviously cant do this until I have somehow joined hometeam and away team as one column.

Any ideas how I would do this?

Comment: Hi, could you please post some sample data and an example of the query output you want? If there is one fixture per team, why would you want to group by team?

Comment: so basically at the moment I am returning 360 fixtures. What I want to do is return the next fixture for each team so this will be 10 fixtures as there are 20 teams. If I could group by team then it would just return 1 fixture per team and I could order it by date to get the next fixtures. The issue I have is obviously I have an awayteam and a hometeam so I cant group by both of these, so I though if I could join hometeam and awayteam to one column then potentially I could group it by team (20 teams) = 10 fixtures. Does this make sense?

Comment: I get it, but the query will depend on the structure of the data and what you want your final output to look like. Are you after a list of 20 teams with the next fixture for each team? or a list of the next 10 fixtures?

Comment: thanks sam, Im after the next fixture for each team, which will only be 10 fixtures :)

Comment: so, you want 20 rows (one for each team) with columns (TeamName, Date, Time, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, Season, Competition)? Do you have any other tables we can work with (eg. `Teams` table)? Your `Fixture` table design isn't conducive to a per-team listing as it currently is.

Comment: "the next fixture for each team"... 20 teams, 20 rows, 10 unique fixtures.

Comment: Just like any football, soccer, basketball, etc sport, you don't want both names to appear on different rows.  However, showing your actual data structures and sample data would help.  There has to be a common date/time that pairs up the teams on who's playing who.

Comment: ok so I have 2 tables as follows:

teams

id, name

fixtures

id, hometeam, awayteam, date, time, season, competition

What I want to achieve is the next 10 fixtures (1 fixture per team whether the team is the hometeam or away team)

I can group by either hometeam or awayteam, but then I wont get 10 fixtures I will get 20. I could actually show all games based on the next date which would work nicely if this is possible, I know if I use group by on Date I will just get 1 of each date

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CONCAT() function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(hometeam, '-', awayteam) as fixture
     , date, time, season, competition
  FROM teams
 GROUP BY fixture
```

Comment: 4 years later someone found ur answer useful